# Loading large images from core data, memory usage spikes after 10

Tags: ios5, core-data

In my iOS app, I have an UIScrollView with paging enabled.  Each page shows a view (with multiple subviews); only 3 "pages" are loaded at any time - the currently viewed one, the one to the left, and the one to the right.  Loading is done lazily in the background.  The app is using ARC.

The view on each page mainly consists of an image, which is retrieved from Core Data.  This image may be large, so a thumbnail is loaded first, and is later replaced by the larger image.  This larger image is actually a scaled down version of what is actually in the data store - the full resolution version is needed for a different screen, but for this image scroller, it just needs to fit the page.  The actual stored image is may be much larger (2448x3264 for a photo from the camera).  Note, the image property in Core Data is set to allow external storage, so in most cases it is not stored in the SQLite database.

Everything "works" fine: the scroller and images load quickly (thumbnail first, larger image soon after), and scrolling is fast.  According to Instruments, memory usage is good also - until the 11th image loads, when memory spikes by ~5MB; subsequent images being loaded are likely to cause more memory spikes (not every one, maybe every other causes another ~5MB spike).  There isn't a specific image causing the spike (I've changed the order of the images that get loaded, its always the 11th).  This memory never seems to be released.

Here's a snippet of the code where the images are loaded in the background:

```
- (void)loadImageWithCardInstanceObjectId:(NSManagedObjectID *)cardInstanceObjectId
                           imageIndex:(NSUInteger)imageIndex
              withInitialImageHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *image))initialImageHandler
                withFinalImageHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *image))finalImageHandler
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *tempMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    tempMoc.parentContext = [[DataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];

    [tempMoc performBlock:^{
        CardInstance *ci = (CardInstance *)[tempMoc objectWithID:cardInstanceObjectId];
        if (ci.cardInstanceImages.count == 0) {
            // no card images, return the default image
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                initialImageHandler([UIImage imageNamed:@"CardNoImage.png"]);
            });
            return;
        }

        // have card images, pick the one according to the passed in index
        UIImage *thumbnail = [[ci.cardInstanceImages objectAtIndex:imageIndex] thumbnailRepresentation];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            initialImageHandler(thumbnail);
        });

        // THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE
        UIImage *fullImage = [[ci.cardInstanceImages objectAtIndex:imageIndex] imageRepresentation];

        CGSize size = fullImage.size;
        CGFloat ratio = 0;
        if (size.width > size.height) {
            ratio = 240.0 / size.width;
        }
        else {
            ratio = 240.0 / size.height;
        }
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ceilf(ratio * size.width), ceilf(ratio * size.height));

        // create the image to display
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0);
        [fullImage drawInRect:rect];
        UIImage *imageToDisplay = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            finalImageHandler(imageToDisplay);
        });
    }];
}
```

In instruments, the responsible library/caller for the allocation is CoreData +[_PFRoutines readExternalReferenceDataFromFile:].

Any thoughts on why this memory spike occurs?  Thanks

Comment: What is the response of the memory size when simulating a memory warning?